# Banco Sqlite fica em formato 'binário' no Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, sqlite, visual-studio-code

Olá, sou inexperiente com VS Code ainda, e estou criando uma aplicação web, mas estou com um problema e não encontrei a solução em nenhum outro site...(estou usando o knex db).
Já tentei apagar e criar de novo, mas sempre fica assim...

[image: esta é a mensagem que aparece... se eu clico em "Do you want to open it anyway, ele fica todo binário."]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O VSCode por padrão não consegue abrir esse tipo de arquivo.

Na verdade, diversas outras extensões e até linguagens não são reconhecidas por ele, para isso é necessário instalar extensões no mesmo.

Existe programas específicos para abrir um arquivo de SQLite, mas caso queira abrir ele no próprio VSCode, uma possibilidade é instalar a extensão de SQLite:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite

Comment: Eu instalei a extensão, obrigado. Dei alguns comandos que falava na documentação,  exclui o db e criei de novo, mas o arquivo continua 'sem formato'... Tem alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Só conheço essa extensão, provável que existam outras, você precisa informar para a extensão qual o arquivo que deseja abrir e ela vai te dar algumas opções em relação ao arquivo aberto, exibindo inclusive as tabelas presentes no arquivo. Você também pode optar por usar um programa específico para isso, como o sqlitestudio.